# HTTP Request Headers not being accepted by server

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, soap

I'm an intern software engineer and have been asked to write a soap script/ REST call that reaches one of  our company servers abroad in order to get a session id and a ticket. I've written the script in JS and have been struggling with the request headers. Our server needs basic Auth of username and password, the headers are as follows: MAN-user-id, MAN-user-password.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) alert('It worked')}; 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Origin, x-requested-with, Content-Type, Accept");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "url");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("MAN-user-id", "username");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("MAN-user-password", "password");
```

upon setting my custom headers I get a 550 response from my server saying I'm missing the username and password and my request headers do not set. I'm using the GET method yet Fiddler shows me using the OPTIONS method (although the "allow-control-request-method" header displays the correct method.)

It seems like every header I set displays as values of the 'Access-Control-Request-Header'
i.e: 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin, man-user-id, man-user-password'

Can someone please explain to me why that is happening?

Thank you

Comment: Umm `Access-Content-*` are **response** headers, not request headers.

Comment: "It seems like every header I set displays as values of the 'Access-Control-Request-Header'" — It would be helpful if you showed us the complete set of request headers being sent, and telling us what method you were using to determine what they were.

Comment: I am using the GET method but when tracked through Fiddler I notice the method changes to the OPTIONS method. I am quite new at web dev and need guidance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests